# how to populate two different columns with one for loop

Tags: django, django-templates

I have an object, I want to loop through the object and populate a page with two columns
I don't know how to seperate the object into two columns.
if I make a div in a loop for each item they just go under each other.

```
{% for listing in listings %}
<div id="listing" class="mb-4 col-md-5 col-sm-3 align-items-center">
        <a href="{% url 'item' listing.item %}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="itemImage col-md-2 col-sm-1">
                <img id="itemImage" class="w-100" src="{% if listing.image %}{{listing.image}}{% else %}{{'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/No_Image_Available.jpg'}}{% endif %}">
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="col-md-10 col-sm-11">
                <h3 id="title">Item: {{listing.item}}</h3>
                <p id="description">Description: {{listing.description}}</p>
                <p id="startingbid">Current Price: {{listing.currentprice}}$</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    {%empty%}
    <p id="nolisting">No items on auction yet.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

this is what I want but I want there to be a new card on the left when forloop count is odd and one on the right when forloopcount is even for example

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you give some examples of what you try to do?

Comment: do you mean that you want something like a table in HTML and do a for loop for the object with separate columns?

Comment: I am trying to loop through a set of objects and make a div for each object.
problem is when I do
{% for item in object %}
<div class="col-md-6">... 

they go under each other, I want a 6 col div for entry 1 on left, another infront of it for entry 2 on the right.
and so forth

Comment: could you please put the view and HTML file to help you because I can't imagine what is your problem even if I understand but i need to be sure what you are trying to say

Comment: I added an html file, this is what im doing but they all stack on each other.
what i need is for there to be 2 different columns so my entire screen is used instead of one column of entries.

Comment: did you try to use a table instead of using div, because your quote about "what i need is for there to be 2 different columns" means that which will achieve your goal

Comment: I will try that, meanwhile I edited again and sent an example of what I want, if you could check it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## In template

```
{% block body %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row g-1">
            {% for listing in myvar %}
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

- You were looping outside the row, but what you need to loop inside the loop and create as many columns as there is data in `listings`.
- I tried this, it works.

Answer (score 1):

actually, you can achieve this with a custom filter.

- go to your app folder that contains those files: "views.py", "urls.py", etc
- then, create a new folder that is called "templatetags"
- add **init**.py file into it and then you can create your custom py file let's call it "even_odd.py"
- add these few lines of code into it.

`from django import template`

```
register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def mod(value):
    number = int(value)
    if number % 2 == 0:
        return "even"
    return "odd"
```

then, in your HTML file, you can filter by this function like so:

- place the file that you created on top of the target file like so:

  `{% load even_odd %}`

then you can like that pseudo code:

```
{% for listing in listings %}
{% with name=forloop.counter|mod %}
{% if name == "even" %}
<div id="listing" class="mb-4 col-md-5 col-sm-3 align-items-center">
        <a href="{% url 'item' listing.item %}">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="itemImage col-md-2 col-sm-1">
                <img id="itemImage" class="w-100" src="{% if listing.image %}{{listing.image}}{% else %}{{'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/14/No_Image_Available.jpg'}}{% endif %}">
            </div>
            <div id="content" class="col-md-10 col-sm-11">
                <h3 id="title">Item: {{listing.item}}</h3>
                <p id="description">Description: {{listing.description}}</p>
                <p id="startingbid">Current Price: {{listing.currentprice}}$</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>
    {% else %}
        # do something else
    {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    {%empty%}
    <p id="nolisting">No items on auction yet.</p>
{% endfor %}
```

this operation has been tested by me